# Postgresql startup error can't create status directory?

Tags: postgresql

I've been running Postgresql for about a week, and I've started and stopped the server a few times without any problems. I stopped it last night because I needed some extra memory. Today when I tried to start it, I got this error message:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster 14 main start
install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘/var/run/postgresql’: No such file or directory
Error: Could not create /var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp: No such file or directory
```

I figured out that pg_ctlcluster tries to change the owner and group of the /var/run/postgresql directory, which wasn't there. Not sure where the second message came from. The pg_stat_tmp directory is where postgres writes status files.  I tried a couple more times to start postgres, mainly to take another look at the error message. On the third try it started, and the required directories magically appeared.

I don't understand why this happened now when it's never happened before.

- Can anybody explain this?
- Is there something I need to do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Use without the `-u postgres`? Check to see if there is a Postgres upgrade in process? Check what the owner and permissions on the directory are set to? Is this machine open to the Internet and if so could it have been hacked?

Comment: On my system (WSL/Ubuntu-20.04) only the postgres user can start the server. It's Ubuntu, so there wouldn't be an upgrade unless I run apt. Everything in the /var/run directory is owned by root, the postresql directories are owned by the postgres user and group. The computer is on my home wifi that requires a password to access, so I suppose it could be hacked but it's not likely.

Comment: Pretty sure you will find that `sudo  pg_ctlcluster 14 main start` will work.  It does on every Ubuntu system I have used. Given that you are using `WSL` all bets are off on sane behavior though.

Comment: I stand corrected. sudo alone is working now. I've started and stopped the server 3 times now with no problem. I can't reproduce the problem so, not a real problem I guess. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: BTW, WSL has been working well. Only hiccup so far was figuring out how to get cron running at startup. There was a solution for that (Windows 11 only), it was just a matter of finding it.